# choosing order of validation methods on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using a validation plugin for my form but after the standard validation i want to add my own methods one of them is a Ajax function which checks if email already exists.

Both work but if i for example enter a email it does the Ajax method, where i want to put a redirect.

the problem is that even if not all fields are filled it always redirects. It has to check al standard validation first, then do the ajax if all is OK then submit how do I do this ?

```
    $( "#registration-form" ).submit(function( event ) {

//vars
var contactemail = $('#contactemail').val();
var contactpassword = $('#contactpassword').val();

//Global validation
$.validate({
      onError : function() {
      //alert('Validation failed');
      return false;
    }
});

//If User create - check if user exists
if($('#contactemail').length && $('#contactemail').val().length && $('#contactpassword').length && $('#contactpassword').val().length)
{
    //Check if can create user
    $.post(jssitebaseUrl+'/ajaxFile.php',{'contactemail':contactemail,'action':'checkOrderEmailId'}, function(output){
        //alert(output);
        if(output == 'UserExist' && contactpassword !=""){
            $("#errors").show();
            $('#errors').html('<p class="i">Can not create account</p>');
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
            return false;
        }
        else if(output == 'CanCreateAccount' || (output == 'UserExist' && contactpassword =="")){
            alert("Maak een guest order aan")

//redirect...
            document.checkoutform.submit();
        }
    });
}
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: use `onSuccess` callback to submit with your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if form is valid before posting:

```
if ( $("#formId").valid() ) {
  // ajax call

}
```

Comment: im  not using that validation plugin,, but this one http://formvalidator.net/#configuration